# use API key in npm @google-cloud/speech

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-speech

Here is the code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/speech

```
   var speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

   var client = speech({
      // optional auth parameters. 
   });
```

How do I pass my API key to authenticate while using @google-cloud/speech? I read the documentation and saw the examples but they don't talk about using API key. Is there any way to get authenticated using the API key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that to use @google-cloud/speech module in your nodejs, you have to have a project created on Google Cloud Platform and need to be logged in to your google account and provide your projectid as a parameter to the speech constructor in order to successfully login.

```
const speechClient = Speech({
     projectId: projectId
});
```

This will authenticate you to make calls to Google Speech API. There is no documentation I could find which enables authentication using the google API key.

Answer (score 3):

You need service account key (it is JSON keyFile). Go to

```
Google speech api dashboard  ->  credentials   ->  create credentials 
->  Service account key   ->  Compute engine default   ->  download json file.
```

Finally add it to config as keyFile, e.g.:

```
{ 
  projectId: 'my-project', 
  keyFile: './myKeyFile.json' 
};
```

*Source:* 
https://bloggerbrothers.com/2017/01/15/the-complete-guide-to-enabling-speech-recognition-on-an-rpi3-in-nodejs/